# Kubuntu 12.04 LTS only boots after crash

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, nvidia, kubuntu

I am having troubles with my Kubuntu 12.04 LTS installation:

If system has shutdown properly before I start the computer, the boot process crashes after the bootloader.
The last output of the boot process is:

```
Starting network connection manager
Starting Bluetooth daemon
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
Starting mDNS/DNS-SD daemon
Starting AppArmor profiles
```

When I then reset the computer it boots without a problem, but the problem above appears again if I restart it normally. It was also started correctly after I performed a system crash with sysrq  c.

The setup is an Itel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2637 v2 @3.50GHz with 4 NVIDIA GeForce GTX 780 Ti.

I have installed the NVIDIA drivers (which changed nothing about the problem) and put 'nomodeset' as a permanent boot option.

How does Grub or the entire boot process behave differently after a system crash than after a normal shutdown?
And what can I do to change this behavior so that it will start correctly all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a hardware problem.

I followed this manual to adjust the blacklist.conf file:

http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Resolve_mei:_Init_hw_failure_or_mei:_initialization_failed

Now the PC boots fine everytime.